# On Bluetooth reception complete auto start exe

Tags: windows, bluetooth, autostart

Suppose I've a setup of my C# project in my mobile, which I want to send to my laptop through Bluetooth. What I was wondering that, Is it possible that after receiving complete on my laptop, the setup should start automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can move the file in the "autostart"

Start. --> Programs --> autostart

move the file inside and it will be start when you start your computer.

is it that what you mean ?

Comment: nop Atlantikdiver I know this and how to start application onStartUp,
but what I was wondering that, at any time when Bluetooth complete receiving at windows side, It then somehow start the .exe file or at least automatically prompts to install the received exe.